# How to use a parameterized route as the root of a StatefulShellRoute with GoRoute

Tags: flutter-go-router

I have a flutter app that I wanted to add stateful navigation to.  I wanted to have it so that you can look at the list of "Foos" and then choose a Foo to look at.  On the Foo detail page I wanted to have 3 tabs and have stateful navigation on those three tabs.  The urls would look something like this:

- /foo

  - /:id

    - /pageA
    - /pageB
    - /pageC

I was following [this example](https://medium.com/@antonio.tioypedro1234/flutter-go-router-the-essential-guide-349ef39ec5b3) to incorporate go_router's `StatefulShellRoute`.  The example looked exactly like I wanted, except when I added it to my app with the parameterized route, I get this error:

```
The default location of a StatefulShellBranch cannot be a parameterized route
```

The error seems to imply that I can't start the stateful branch on a page that is parameterized, but that's where I want my nested navigation with tabs to start.  Is there a way around this or another way to accomplish this?

Here's the router I was trying to setup:

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return MyHomePage();
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
            path: 'foo',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const FooListScreen();
            },
            routes: [
              StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
                  builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
                    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("fix this scaffold")));
                  },
                  branches: [
                    StatefulShellBranch(
                        navigatorKey: _fooNavigatorKey,
                        routes: [
                          GoRoute(
                              name: "fooDetails",
                              path: ":id",
                              builder: (context, state) => FooDetailScreen(
                                  id: int.parse(
                                      state.pathParameters['id'] ?? "0"))),
                        ]),
                  ]),
            ]),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

I'm using Flutter 3.7.11 and go_router 8.0.5

Answer (score 1):

one workaround could be to add a dummy route before your parameterized route, see this example:

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return MyHomePage();
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
            path: 'foo',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const FooListScreen();
            },
            routes: [
              StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
                  builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
                    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("fix this scaffold")));
                  },
                  branches: [
                    StatefulShellBranch(
                        navigatorKey: _fooNavigatorKey,
                        routes: [

                          GoRoute(
                              name: "dummyRoute",
                              path: "/dummy",
                              builder: (context, state) => DummyScreen(),
    ),
                          GoRoute(
                              name: "fooDetails",
                              path: ":id",
                              builder: (context, state) => FooDetailScreen(
                                  id: int.parse(
                                      state.pathParameters['id'] ?? "0"))),
                        ]),
                  ]),
            ]),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Worked in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can audoredirect your route with params:

```
StatefulShellBranch(
  navigatorKey: shellUniqeKey,
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: "fooDetails",
      path: "/fooDetails",
      redirect: (context, state) =>
          '/fooDetails/${state.pathParameters['id']}',
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: ':id',
          builder: (context, state) => const FooDetailScreen(id: state.pathParameters['id']),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```